# How do I automatically set to_user (receiver) in my message form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Models

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reciever", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I am pretty sure I have the right idea, and that is to first create a button:

```
<a href="{% url 'send-message-to' profile.user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Send a message</a>
```

I then pass the profile id to my CreateView and then query the user with the received pk:

```
class MessageCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Message

    fields = ['title', 'msg_content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.sender = self.request.user
        form.instance.receiver = User.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))


        return super().form_valid(form)
```

But it is not working as intended. I am receiving the error

```
IntegrityError at /messages/create/1/
null value in column "reciever_id" violates not-null constraint
```

For some reason the code I have written is not filling in the receiver id. `form.instance.receiver = User.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))`

How can I get my form to automatically set the reciever (to_user) in my form?

What is happening right now is that when I try to create a message I get a dropdown of all the users available which is not desired.

Comment: You just have a typo; you're setting `receiver` but your field is named `reciever`. You should probably change the field name, since that's a spelling error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks Daniel. English is hard :(

Comment: I before E, *except after C*...